# Unable to connect to rackspace cloud server using putty after resize

Tags: ubuntu, rackspace-cloud

I own a rackspace cloud server which worked fine. I used WinSCP and Putty to connect to it and manage it. Then I re-sized the instance adding some more memory. Now whenever I try connecting to it through putty it accepts the username but even for the correct password it returns "Access Denied".

There is nothing wrong with my putty settings because I can connect to my other Raskspace Cloud servers. Its not working only for this instance.

I restarted ssh several times, regenerated the keys, reinstalled ssh and openssh-server and so one bu no avail.

Comment: @lynxman is right — please contact Rackspace Cloud Support via Live Chat or by calling 1-877-934-0407. You can also contact me via email: robot AT rackspace DOT com. ~ Robert Taylor, Sr Sys Engineer, Rackspace Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a corrupted file on your server, possibly as a product of this server resize, if I were you I would contact Rackspace support and ask them to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove ssh
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server

rm -rf /etc/ssh 
mkdir /etc/ssh
sudo apt-get install ssh openssh-server
```

And bingo it worked.

Comment: So looks like I was right, happy to see it worked :)